# Adobe Air 2.5+ @font-face and the HTMLLoader

Tags: air, adobe, font-face

Can someone post the proper syntax for using @font-face with the HTMLloader. I'm loading an HTML string directly into the loader and it will render normal CSS, but I can't get it to load the TTF I'm referencing with @font-face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Adobe only has Adobe Air 1.5 built into it, that was my problem. Using this tutorial, I was able to upgrade to use Adobe Air 2.7 using this tutorial,

http://blog.prevail.co.nz/2011/06/21/overlaying-air2-7-in-flash-cs5/

After upgrading the @font-face started working, but I still didn't like it cause the fonts had no anti-alias smoothing, the fonts render like they would in a browser using web safe fonts.